# Issues deploying to heroku after database migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an application that runs locally but does not run after deploying to heroku. On Heroku, the application defaults to the "Welcome Aboard" page. That file was removed locally.

I've been trying to resolve this issue for hours, and tried the suggestions made in other Stackoverflow answers, the most common of which is:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
heroku restart
```

to no avail.

The issue seems to be related to the database migrations that I performed earlier. The logs show:

```
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CorporationsController#new as HTML
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/corporations/new" for 64.236.139.254 at 2013-02-10 06:58:31 +0000
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:     <%= f.text_field :incorporation_date %>
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered corporations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (51.7ms)
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered corporations/_form.html.erb (36.4ms)
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 60ms
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:   <div class="field">
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:     <%= f.label :incorporation_date %><br />
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `incorporation_date' for #<Corporation:0x00000001e8c5c8>):
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/corporations/_form.html.erb:28:in `block in _app_views_corporations__form_html_erb__2627361166614576795_14624240'
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     29:   </div>
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/corporations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_corporations_new_html_erb___3891731594578946395_15501200'
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     30:   <div class="actions">
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:   </div>
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/corporations/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_corporations__form_html_erb__2627361166614576795_14624240'
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:     31:     <%= f.submit %>
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/corporations_controller.rb:34:in `new'
2013-02-10T06:58:31+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I have three migration files that look like this:

**20130209192118_create_corporations.rb**

```
class CreateCorporations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :corporations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :shares
      t.string :par_value
      t.string :incorporation_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**20130209231940_add_filing_date_to_corporations.rb**

```
class AddFilingDateToCorporations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :corporations, :filing_date, :date
  end
end
```

**20130209232108_remove_incorporation_date_from_corporations**

```
class RemoveIncorporationDateFromCorporations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :corporations, :incorporation_date
  end

  def down
    add_column :corporations, :incorporation_date, :string
  end
end
```

Really appreciate any thoughts...

Answer (score 3):

In your last migration you remove `incorporation_date` column from your table, but in your `corporations/_form.html.erb` you're calling `f.label :incorporation_date`. It's strange that it works locally; may be you didn't run latest migrations or edited table manually.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why it is referencing _form.html.erb. I switched to haml 25 commits ago. Seems like it is not seeing _form.html.haml?

Comment: apparently haml has a lower priority, try to just remove erb model

Comment: Thanks for the input. Not sure how to proceed given that _form.html.erb has been removed from (or rather renamed in) the directory. Looking into this further now.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I was able to resolve the issue. Quite stupid. I ended up doing git add -u to track deleted files, which got rid of the .erb files and resolved the issue with Heroku. Thank you so much for putting me on the right track.